# Handling large data in JasperReports Bar Graph

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I'm using `JasperReports 4.0.1`
I am having large data set to be represented in Grouped Bar Graph

The bar are crammed and rendered very close to each other.

[image: Jasper Report Horizontal Bar Graph with large data]

Is there any way to scale it properly?

Or to give record number limit , after which `JasperReports` can split it in multiple graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart customizers certainly give you full control to do whatever you like. But you could perhaps still do some interesting things without a chart customizer in this case.

I'm not sure what you mean by "scale it properly", so I can't comment on that part.

You could add a group to the report to prevent the chart from having too many values. For example you could group on an expression like this:

```
new Integer($V{REPORT_COUNT}/10)
```

That way you would get only 10 items in each group. Put the chart into the group footer. In the case where you have fewer than 10 rows you'll get a single chart. If you have more rows, then you'll get multiple charts.

Your grouping would probably be more complex than just counting the rows, but the same idea should apply.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do customize charts like that in jasper-reports is to implement your own chart customizer class. Here is an article I found [link](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/chart-customizers-1/)